# Can't create multiple folders using md for UNC path

Tags: shell, command-line, permissions, windows-server-2008

This is something that is mystifying me.

We have a remote share \SomeMachine\Mirror
with a sub folder \Reports

so 
\\SomeMachine\Mirror\Reports

We then have a batch command that runs
md "\\SomeMachine\Mirror\Reports\YYYY\YYYY-MM\YYYY-MM-DD"

where the date parts are substituted for the current date.

I can run this command from my machine and it correctly creates the path,
but from the server (Windows Server 2008 R2), it fails saying "The directory or file cannot be created".  Stranger still, if I do the md in stages, first creating the YYYY path then the YYYY-MM path, it works fine.  Not sure if there are any permissions that would prevent one method and not the other?

Both command shells state their version as 6.1.7601, and mkdir /? states that it will create intermediate paths.

Anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation on different servers, I confirmed that the behaviour was different between two otherwise identical servers.  A restart of the server exhibiting the problem resolved this.  There were no other (visible) symptoms, so chalk this up to "glitch" likely linked to a server software update.